# Select multiple images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this UITableView which is displaying images, downloaded rom a database, as a matrix: 4 images in each table row.

To be able to select images from the views I'm using a UITapGestureRecognizer. To make each selection unique I've been trying to tag each tap recognizer and each imageView. That's where the problem is...

I've put a log within the for-loop that is creating and tagging the imageViews and recognizers and I can see in the output that they pass through all the values. However when I try to get the tag by later pressing an image I always get "3" (the last number in the table row). This makes me think the tags are simlpy overwriting eachother even though I'm creating a new object in each loop. Either that or I'm reading it out the wrong way.

Unrelated parts cut out.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++){

asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc]
                               initWithFrame:frame];

[asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];
    asyncImage.tag = i; 
    NSLog(@"TAG %d", asyncImage.tag);
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
    tapRecognizer.view.tag = i;
    NSLog(@"TapTAG %d", asyncImage.tag);

    [asyncImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

And the method:

```
- (void)handleTap{
NSLog(@"TAP %d", self.tapRecognizer.view.tag);

}
```

If you think I'm doing it all totally wrong, a light push in the right direction is always welcome!

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line has no effect until the gesture recognizer has been added to a view:

```
tapRecognizer.view.tag = i;
```

This is because `tapRecognizer`'s `view` is initially `nil`. Make the assignment on the last line of your `for` loop to correct this problem.

Also your `NSLog` is always showing the tag of the last recognizer that you have added

```
self.tapRecognizer.view.tag // Instance variable
```

not the one that fired the event. Change `handleTap` as follows:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) tapRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"TAP %d", tapRecognizer.view.tag);
}
```

You should also replace the `tapRecognizer` instance variable with a local variable in the method that adds the recognizer to the view, and add a colon `:` to your selector name:

```
action:@selector(handleTap:)
//              HERE: ----^
```

Comment: Isn't that what this line does?

   [asyncImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

asyncImage is a UIImageView.

Comment: @user1534948 Yes, but it does it too late: the call of `tapRecognizer.view.tag=i` has to come after, not before the view has been set. Currently, `tapRecognizer.view` is `nil` at the time of the call, so `setTag` message is set to `nil`, and is therefore ignored.

Comment: I just tried it. It makes sense what youre saying, but they're still all returning 3... I have a feeling the problem might be how I'm returning the variable. The handleTap method is returning THE actual tap and not the last one created right?

Comment: @user1534948 This is strange. Is the `for` loop inside a block that is called asynchronously by any chance?

Comment: Nope, it's right inside the tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.
The returning was alright then? Maybe that I'm using the recognizer as an instance variable? Just brainstorming a bit...

Comment: @user1534948 Ah, you are right, take a look at the update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your time! Great explanation so I won't repeat it either!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong in the loop.
Your loop is run 4 times and every time you run the loop you store AsyncImageView to the asyncImage variable (local or instance?). So the first time you run the loop, you create an object and store it at the asyncImage location, the second time this is overwritten, the third....

You have initialized 4 ImageViews, but you are only referencing to the last one. And the last one holds the correct GestureRecognizer, you want.

When do you add the ImageView to a view?

If you use the instance varable and overwrite it directly, all the other ImageViews you added to the screen point to the pointer of `asyncImage`.  And the pointer - after running 4 times the loop and exchanging asyncImage data - points to the last image in the loop.

Hope you understand, what the problem is here.